# SparkSQL:Avg based on a column after GroupBy

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have an rdd of student grades and I need to first group them by the first column which is university and then show the average of student count in each course like this. What is the easiest way to do this query?

```
+----------+-------------------+                                                              
|university|  avg of students   |
+----------+--------------------+
|       MIT|    3               |
| Cambridge|    2.66
```

Here is the dataset.

```
case class grade(university: String, courseId: Int, studentId: Int, grade: Double)

val grades = List(grade(
grade("Cambridge", 1, 1001, 4),
grade("Cambridge", 1, 1004, 4),
grade("Cambridge", 2, 1006, 3.5),
grade("Cambridge", 2, 1004, 3.5),
grade("Cambridge", 2, 1002, 3.5),
grade("Cambridge", 3, 1006, 3.5),
grade("Cambridge", 3, 1007, 5),
grade("Cambridge", 3, 1008, 4.5),
grade("MIT", 1, 1001, 4),
grade("MIT", 1, 1002, 4),
grade("MIT", 1, 1003, 4),
grade("MIT", 1, 1004, 4),
grade("MIT", 1, 1005, 3.5),
grade("MIT", 2, 1009, 2))
```

Comment: what do you mean by student numbers .. ? did you mean student count ?

Comment: yes exactly. Average of student count in courses in each university. it will be (2+3+3)/3 in Cambridge and (5+1)/2 in MIT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
gradesRdd.map({ case Grade(university: String, courseId: Int, studentId: Int, gpa: Int) => 
   ((university),(courseId))}).mapValues(x => (x, 1))
   .reduceByKey((x, y) => (x._1 + y._1, x._2 + y._2))
   .mapValues(y => 1.0 * y._1 / y._2).collect
   res73: Array[(String, Double)] = Array((Cambridge,2.125), (MIT,1.1666666666666667))
```

Answer (score 2):

1) First groupBy university

2) then get course count per university

3) then groupBy courseId

4) then get student count per course

```
grades.groupBy(_.university).map { case (k, v) =>
    val courseCount = v.map(_.courseId).distinct.length
    val studentCountPerCourse = v.groupBy(_.courseId).map { case (k, v) => v.length }.sum
    k -> (studentCountPerCourse.toDouble / courseCount.toDouble)
  }
```

**Scala REPL**

```
scala> val grades = List(
      grade("Cambridge", 1, 1001, 4),
      grade("Cambridge", 1, 1004, 4),
      grade("Cambridge", 2, 1006, 3.5),
      grade("Cambridge", 2, 1004, 3.5),
      grade("Cambridge", 2, 1002, 3.5),
      grade("Cambridge", 3, 1006, 3.5),
      grade("Cambridge", 3, 1007, 5),
      grade("Cambridge", 3, 1008, 4.5),
      grade("MIT", 1, 1001, 4),
      grade("MIT", 1, 1002, 4),
      grade("MIT", 1, 1003, 4),
      grade("MIT", 1, 1004, 4),
      grade("MIT", 1, 1005, 3.5),
      grade("MIT", 2, 1009, 2))
// grades: List[grade] = List(...)

scala> grades.groupBy(_.university).map { case (k, v) =>
      val courseCount = v.map(_.courseId).distinct.length
      val studentCountPerCourse = v.groupBy(_.courseId).map { case (k, v) => v.length }.sum
      k -> (studentCountPerCourse.toDouble / courseCount.toDouble)
    }
// res2: Map[String, Double] = Map("MIT" -> 3.0, "Cambridge" -> 2.6666666666666665)
```

Comment: @sina you can also thank me by upvoting by answer :)

Comment: This solution isn't written in spark.

Comment: @eliasah this is just to give an idea of what to do to get the answer .. I think  it can be translated to respective domain to make it work